# Annoying Cordova + android + JSON behavior

Tags: android, json, cordova

I have been far too many hours with this one. I am trying to execute the seemingly simple line of code:

```
$.getJSON(SERVER_URL + '/path/', function(data) {alert(data);});
```

which works just fine with `cordova serve`. When I build the Android Apk, that line never gets executed (although everything is in place and I know for sure that the line is reached). There is no request received on the server part.
I have been looking into this for hours, so I have tried everything possible (whitelist plugin, check my config.xml file, check for INTERNET permission in the manifest file, etc.). I cannot believe that there is no way to do this :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Very stupid of me. Turns out that there were permission problems, but by the time I had solved it, my server (also in development) had died silently. I just leave this for anyone that might have a similar problem. Suspect your server.